# Is there a way to copy the text to clipboard with the formatting(Styles)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I want to copy the section with styles to clipboard, for example,

```
Text("test",style:TextStyle(color:Colors.red))
```

for example, I want to copy above with colors to clipboard, Is there a way to do so ?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Is there any alternative options, like using web view packages

Comment: I don't know about the web, but in mobile you can't do that.